# Why are these two implementations different?

Tags: go, higher-order-functions

I am newbie in Golang - While trying to rewrite the following to a single thread implementation.

```
.....
run := func(handler func(chan<- modify), threads int) <-chan modify {
    result := make(chan modify)
    go func() {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                handler(result)
            }()
        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(result)
    }()
    return result
}


modifyAgg := run(func(result chan<- modify) {
aggre := run(func(result chan<- modify) {
    u.addAgg(slices, result)  // returns result channel
}, u.threads.GrpTxns)

....
```

In the above code the variable addAgg is of type chan<- modify. The following is not - get error while ranging over the variable aggre  "cannot range over addAgg(type func())"

```
aggre := func() {
    result:= make(chan modify)
    defer close(result)
    u.addAgg(slices, result) // returns result channel
}
```

How to change the second implementation to mimic the first one? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement this in single thread...

```
aggre := func() <-chan modify{
        result:= make(chan modify, 50) // make it non blocking
        u.addAgg(slices, result)
        defer close(result)
        return result
    }()
```